# Bilingual hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

I use the following preable in my document and I have a problem regardind hyphenation in new lines when I use both english and greek in my text. When I use only greek without the `babel` package then everything works fine and I have the proper hyphenation in greek text. But when I write in both languages if I have the `babel` package loaded then I don't get greek hyphenation. If I erase it I don't have english hyphenation. How can I fix that so to have hyphenation in both languages?

The problem occurs in this paragraph:

"Ένα πρότυπο (ή αντικείμενο) καθορίζεται από ένα διάνυσμα μετρήσεων (measurements) που ονομάζονται χαρακτηριστικά (features). Το διάνυσμα ονομάζεται διάνυσμα χαρακτηριστικών (feature vector)."

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{xgreek}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

Text Here!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `xgreek` (and also `xltxtra`, you just need `fontspec`, instead): it fights with `babel`; then `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` should do. Or use `polyglossia`.

Comment: @egreg I did what you said and I still get overful boxes because of the lack of hyphenation.

Comment: I get none, with your example. ;-)

Comment: The paragraph in wquestion is this:

"Ένα πρότυπο (ή αντικείμενο) καθορίζεται από ένα διάνυσμα μετρήσεων (measurements) που ονομάζονται χαρακτηριστικά (features). Το διάνυσμα ονομάζεται διάνυσμα χαρακτηριστικών (feature vector)."

Comment: Please, add it to your question.

Comment: Ok I edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use babel with English and Greek. But you must define what language you use.

You can do this with `\selectlanguage` and `\foreignlanguage`

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,greek,english,]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.7in, bottom=1.2in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[]{babel}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text,
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

Wrong here:

Ένα πρότυπο (ή αντικείμενο) καθορίζεται από ένα διάνυσμα μετρήσεων (measurements) που
ονομάζονται χαρακτηριστικά (features). Το διάνυσμα ονομάζεται διάνυσμα 
χαρακτηριστικών (feature vector)

Correct here:

\selectlanguage{greek}
Ένα πρότυπο (ή αντικείμενο) καθορίζεται από ένα διάνυσμα μετρήσεων 
(\foreignlanguage{english}{measurements}) που ονομάζονται χαρακτηριστικά 
(\foreignlanguage{english}{features}). Το διάνυσμα ονομάζεται διάνυσμα 
χαρακτηριστικών (\foreignlanguage{english}{feature vector})


\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this very painstaking? I mean all I want is to write in 2 languages. Also I guess there are people who write in 3 or 4 languages some texts in their documents what are they doing? :P

Comment: How do you think TeX could recognize which language a text is? and inside this text to detect foreign words? For combinations of greek/latin writing (and e.g. arabic...) it may be possible (You could ask a new question for this). if `\foreignlanguage{english}{...}` is to long, you mey define a short version like `newcommand{\grk}[1]{\foreignlanguage{greek}{#1}}`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer and your comments.